# List all packages at a deb-src using apt-get?

Tags: 12.10, apt, lubuntu

Is there a way to get a listing of packages at a deb-src "resource" using apt-get ?

like

```
apt-get <deb-src> *python*
```

to "see" whats available ?

I installed a "base" lubuntu install and am looking to see what packages are available to build it up with (its an old school toshiba nb305 netbook, rocking the 2GB Dimm, lookout).

Thanks.

Comment: You can use: apt-cache search -n python; to search only package names that contain 'python' (omit the -n to search everything). Not sure if that is what you meant, since deb-src repos are for source code for building packages, but it seems like you just want to install some extra binary packages from the command line.

Comment: I could've been asking the wrong question, it sounds like this is what I need. Now that you told me how to check the available local packages, is there a way to check what packages are available remotely, or does the cache keep an updated list of them ?

Comment: Yes, apt-cache will search package information for all the repos you have added and run: apt-get update; for, so all the standard ubuntu stuff (main, universe, multiverse) plus any ppas you have added or external repos. You can use: apt-cache policy packagename; to see which repository it comes from and its current installed status.

Comment: Nice. You should put your comment into and answer so I can accept it and stuff... Thanks a lot, I only get to use ubuntu after coding allll day, and so am kinda tired, and is why I turned for help here with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To search for packages from the command line, you can use:

```
apt-cache search -n pattern
```

to search only package names, or omit the -n switch to search descriptions as well. This will search all of the archives you have listed in your /etc/apt/sources.list, and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ directory, assuming:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

has been run first. This includes standard Ubuntu repositories such as main, universe, multiverse, and any PPA or external repositories listed. It also supports POSIX regex patterns (see the regex(7) manpage), so you can do interesting things like:

```
apt-cache search -n '^python-.{3}$'
```

to search for only packages that have the form python-ABC for any characters ABC.

To check the installed status from the command line, as well as which repository the package originates from, you can use:

```
apt-cache policy package-name
```